# User defined function over all rows in window

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a set of timestamped location data with a set of string feature ids that are attached to each location.  I'd like to use a Window in spark to pull together an array of all of these feature id strings across the current N and next N rows, ala:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
windowSpec = Window \
    .partitionBy(df['userid']) \
    .orderBy(df['timestamp']) \
    .rowsBetween(-50, 50)

dataFrame = sqlContext.table("locations")
featureIds = featuresCollector(dataFrame['featureId']).over(windowSpec)
dataFrame.select(
  dataFrame['product'],
  dataFrame['category'],
  dataFrame['revenue'],
  featureIds.alias("allFeatureIds"))
```

Is this possible with Spark and if so, how do I write a function like featuresCollector that can collect all the feature ids in the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark UDFs cannot be used for aggregations. Spark provides a number of tools ([`UserDefinedAggregateFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction), [`Aggregators`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator), `AggregateExpressions`) which can be used for custom aggregations, and some of these can be used with windowing, but none can be defined in Python.

If all you want is to collect records, `collect_list` should do the trick. Please keep in mind that is a **very expensive** operation.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

featureIds = collect_list('featureId').over(windowSpec)
```